# if statement if there is no value returned

Tags: php

I have some data pulled from a user section of a json file. I am able to get the info but have an issue I am unfamiliar with.

certain fields are removed from the json file based on the user. if the user starts a game then

```
echo $item['game']['name'];
```

outputs valid result, if the user leaves a game and you refresh it says game is undefiend index.

I have never seen a field removed from a json file but that is what it does.

so i tried to test a if statement if its not null do this if its null do this but it does not do anything if its null

```
foreach($result['members'] as $item) {
    echo $item['username'];
    echo $item['status'];
    echo $item['channel_id'];

    if ($result['members']['game'] !== NULL){
        echo 'nothing';
    }else{
        echo 'user in game';
    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably use `isset` or `array_key_exists`

Comment: are you sure its NULL and not just empty string? Maybe just use `if (!empty($result['members']['game']))`

Comment: well when i look at the json i see all field but when i enter a game then the json adds a game field to it

Comment: You'll want to check on `empty($item['game'])` then. In your example you are looking at something that wont ever exist.

Answer (score -1):

The json file is a function of the app that is maintaining it.  But if you want to be able to check that var, and you don't know if it is SET or not, use the isset() function.  Example:

```
if (isset ($value)) {
   // $value is not defined or is null
   echo "No value :(\n";
}
else {
   // $value is set.
   echo "There is a value!\n";
}
```

You can find more doc here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php